# Import failed with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE although declared in the manifest

Tags: android, kotlin

I get an import error on the following code section. Have imported everything necessary in the manifest

```
     bottomFilter.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImageToShot).setOnClickListener {
        when {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {

                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }

            else -> {
                selectImage()
            }
        }
    }
```

> Unresolved reference: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


 ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you import your app's manifest:

```
import com.example.app.Manifest
```

And not Android's manifest

```
import android.Manifest
```